# Disable the default-jar execution

Tags: maven-2, jar, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I am using Maven Assembly plugin to pack a jar file.

But when I run `mvn package`, maven always trigger the [jar:jar {execution: default-jar}] to create a default jar file.

So I will have 2 jar files (one created by Assembly plugin and one created by Maven jar which i don't want to be created).

How can I turn off the default-jar execution?

In my `pom.xml`, I am using: `<packaging>jar</packaging>`.

I don't want to change it to `<packaging>pom</packaging>`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> (...) So i will have 2 jar files (one created by assembly plugin and one created by maven jar which i dont want to be created).

Looks like you're doing pretty complicated things. Maybe Maven is not the right tool in your case.

> How can I turn off the execution: default-jar.

You can set the `<phase>` of the corresponding execution to something unknown, like `none`:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <phase>none</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id>
        <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
        <phase>package</phase>
        <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
          <!-- goals == mojos -->
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This seems to work as long as you're providing something else to be installed, like an assembly (I only tested `install`). But of course, this is a hack.

Comment: It is a hack, but it's great to know this hack. Thanks! (+1)

Comment: BTW, do you ever sleep? You're on CET too, aren't you?

Comment: @seanizer: LOL. Yes I do :) And no, I'm currently not, I'm moving.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a hack.  More of a way to turn off the 'default' plugins with maven when you don't need them.  Beside, even the execution of the maven-jar-plugin adds time to the build even when there is nothing to build.  So why even incur the time expense for something that does nothing?

Comment: Thanks everybody. Special thanks to Pascal. I just start working with Maven 1 month ago. It is not easy for me. With your helping, now i feel better with Maven.

Comment: I know it has been a while, but using Maven 3.8.1 I get the error `Source must refer to an existing file, got [...]/target`. Obviously the target folder is empty. Can this hack be updated to current Maven?

Comment: This answer is still correct and works nicely in current Maven versions, I tried with 3.9.4 just to be sure. I also use it in some projects. If you disagree, open a new question and post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. P.S.: If you add `<archive><manifest><mainClass>my.package.Main</mainClass></manifest></archive>`, the resulting JAR will even be executable.

Comment: I cannot verify my problem within a MWE, looks like there was a problem somewhere else in my POM. Sorry that I did not realise myself.

Answer (score 4):

While not a direct answer to the question, you could exclude the jar created by *maven jar* using `<useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>`