# How can I stop a default plugin execution?

Tags: javascript, maven, maven-plugin

I'm using a javascript maven plugin. I like the war-package goal and want to use it.

However it also comes with a jsunit goal bound to the test phase. This part of the plugin isn't great so I want to just turn it off. How can I do this?

Plugin xml is below.

Edit : Have tried adding executions with phase none, but the goals still run.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.javascript</groupId>
    <artifactId>javascript-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copyDependenciesForJasmine</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>war-package</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/javascript</webappDirectory>
                <scriptsDirectory>src</scriptsDirectory>
                <libsDirectory>../dependencies</libsDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jsunit</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-tests</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What is the url of the plugin home page?  Google shows me http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/javascript-maven-plugin/ which seems to have different versions and goals than specified above

Comment: It's a somewhat defunct plugin http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/javascript-maven-plugin/war-package-mojo.html and web page seems a bit broken. I was hoping that my question was not plugin specific. Various plugins bind themselves by default to a phase, I was hoping there was a generic way to override that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101750/disable-the-execution-default-jar). You may just specify execution phase to `none` on the specific plugin.

Comment: I tried adding phase none. The goals still run. Updated in the question.