# How to force manual execution of a maven plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Is there a way in maven to force a plugin to only execute manually. for example I have the sql plugin which will be creating some tables, I don't want this plugin to run all the time with every build i want it only run when I tell maven to run that plugin. How can a plugin be configured to run manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most plugins won't execute automatically unless they are [bound to a build phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag). You should find that your plugin won't execute unless you specify it on the command line: `mvn plugin:goal`.

If the plugin is already bound automatically to a phase, you can undo this by binding it to a non-existent phase (`none` is the traditional choice). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4103159/474189) for an example of this.